# Can I use this laptop in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, unity, nvidia

**ASUS A53SV-SX538V**

Technical:

**Processor**: Intel Core i7-2670QM (4x2, 20 GHz / 6 MB cache).

**Display / Resolution**: 15.6 "Glossy / 1366x768.

**RAM / HDD**: 4 GB DDR3 RAM / 500 GB (5400 rpm).

**Graphics Card**: nVidia GT 540M with 2 GB DDR3 (dedicated).

**Dimensions / Weight**: 378x253x28, 3 to 34.9 mm / 2.60 kg

The graph that integrates a dedicated nVidia GeForce GT 540m 2 GB of DDR3 memory, with which we can take current games with games at medium-high quality depending on the requirements of each title, you can look at a list of the games most prominent and of how to play with this chart here. Includes Optimus technology will allow us to save energy, thus extending the battery life if you do not need much graphics horsepower. With CUDA instructions will help the processor complex calculations provided that the programs that implement them.

Regards, thanks.

Comment: The only concern you should have with the spec is the optimus technology... just search for "optimus" on the forum and you'll see the questions and issues with this technology.

Comment: So I put this question because optimus, you can disable or could do about it?

Comment: optimus isnt handled very well in linux - you have to switch either the integrated graphics or the higher nvidia card - you cant have both running at the same time.  You need to manually install the bumblebee PPA to do this and do some other config...  I would urge you to look at the related questions first to see if you are comfortable with doing this tweaking - Otherwise just stick to buying an integrated graphics solution - preferably NVIDIA or Intel.

Comment: Some tell me to install bumbleble and other Ironhead, what do I do? Do I follow these steps apostl3pol this user?(http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11532163#post11532163)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cant choose between the IGP and the discrete card. You either work with both with buggy bumblebee or disable the discrete card.

Optimus tecnology doesnt allow you to choose between both of them. The IGP is the one displaying the video, the discrete cards only is turned on when is required (heavy load scenario), but the IGP is the one displaying the video on the screen always.

Nvidia is not interested in bringing Optimus to Linux, due a lot of work needed in the X and the few percentage of us using Linux.

My advice is if you are gonna buy a Sandy Bridge, buy a laptop without a discrete card and save some money, or at least, an ATI card. Linux Hybrid Graphics with ATI via vgaswitcheroo works better, but is far from perfect.

- [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Answer (score 1):

Yes ..Of Cource..You  laptop use can easily and Fast ...

Comment: its not easy and its not fast... see better optimus answer

Answer (score 0):

You laptop can easily run Ubuntu 11.10. I'm running 11.10 on a 4 year old Vio with a Centrino processor and 2 GB ram and it runs fine.

Comment: Your centrino observation is good - but does not apply in the OP case since his laptop is optimus technology

Comment: you don't ask this type of question if you want to know what the Minimum requirements for 11.10 is. He wants to know if it's compatible, not the same...